# How to customize rPlot title ( font size , font,..)?

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts, polychart

How can I change the font size of an  `rPlot`  title?

```
library(rCharts)
p1 <- rPlot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, type = 'point')
p1$set(title = "title",fontSize = '50px')
p1
```

Comment: I have posted this question on the [polychart repo](https://github.com/Polychart/polychart2/issues/16). Based on the answer, I will post the rCharts solution.

Comment: @Ramnath excellent. Do you mean , you will post the solution in the ploychart repo?

Comment: No. I meant that I will post the rCharts solution here, once I know how it is handled natively in Polychart, since rCharts is just a wrapper.